# How to generate an event with SAM local generate event with queryparameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam-cli

I can generate an event like this in SAM

```
sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy --method GET --path document --body "{"test": "1", "tests2": "2"}" > local-event.json
```

But this does not really help me because I do not send a body to my endpoint but I send queryparameters like this:

```
localhost:3000/path?test=1&test2=2
```

How can I generate an event with query string parameters in SAM for local testing instead of using curl/testing against the local api gateway.

Answer (score 9):

To send query string parameters using `sam local invoke`:

1. Generate your event: `sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy --method GET > local-event.json`
2. In the generated file `local-event.json`, there should be an object key called `"queryStringParameters"`. Simply add `"key": "value"` pairs to this object. Save.
3. Run `sam local invoke -e local-event.json`

**Source**: https://seanjziegler.com/how-to-build-an-api-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-using-aws-sam/#5-testing-the-api-with-sam-local-

Comment: It's ridiculous how tough it is to find this info. Thank you.

Comment: @rhlsthrm Tell me about it! Fortunately had just ran into the problem myself when I saw this question.